# In a contribution, we have form , after user submits and when we manually add the payment, it's not changing status to new from pending in membership

Tags: wordpress, civimember, status

We have created a contribution form in civicrm, after user submits and when we manually add the payment, it's not changing status to new from pending in membership, earlier it was working well, we have facing the problem since we have migrated to the new server, we have setup crm in Wordpress.
We are unable to figure out what could have gone wrong as we have checked all the settings but they are exactly same as previous servers settings. we have also imported the same database form previous server and exported in new.

Edited:

So We have created an contribution form in civicrm. the flow goes as follows:

User fills the application form,

Once the application form submitted then admin verifies, changes the membership status to verified form pending manually,

User gets the verified email and does the offline payment(it's clients requirement to do offline payment).

Once the payment is verified then admin adds the payment details in contribution payment section.

Once the contribution status is completed then membership should assign and status should be automatically set to the new : this step was earlier working fine in old server but in current server it's not updating the status and also membership is not getting assigned to the user...everything else is working fine also the status is reverting back to the pending instead of new.

We are using wordpress version 5.9.3, Civicrm: Version 5.29.1
server php version 7.4

Comment: Are you using short code in Wordpress?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange! It would be helpful if you could provide a bit more detail about your system. This will make it easier for people to answer your question. Could you edit your question to add details about the version of CiviCRM and WordPress you are using. Also, how are users making payments?

Comment: You've tagged this as 'webform-civicrm' but said you are using WordPress. Given that webform only works with Drupal, I guess this is a mistake so have changed the tags.

Comment: I have updated the post and added more detailed information about the flow and configuration, can you please check?

Comment: @Ramesh, no I am not yet using shortcode.

Comment: @SayaLi This can happen for many reason - try updating your CiviCRM - Better to create a testing site and then upgrade your CiviCRM to the latest version (then test) - Else remove all your extension and then try - it should work

Comment: two questions 1/ you said "then admin verifies, changes the membership status to verified form pending manually" - do you mean they are setting the Memb Status to 'overridden'?

Comment: 2/ you say "admin adds the payment details in contribution payment section", but not clear they are adding this as a contribution 'to the membership'.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your WordPress install doesn't have a cron job running to automatically kick off scheduled jobs. Check this by going to:

administer > system settings > scheduled jobs

Scroll down to find the item:

Update Membership Statuses (Daily)

In the third column you will see the last time this was run - if it's not recent then this isn't being executed regularly.

You can use the "more" item at the far right and choose "execute now" and see if that causes it to update the way you would expect.